# Memory leak with strings?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, memory-leaks

I'm new to C, so this may be obvious, but I'm still not sure. Java took care of this for me ^^

I have a table of replacements, input string, and a function [str_replace](http://www.binarytides.com/str_replace-for-c/) which does some work on the string. `str_replace` internally calls malloc to get space for the new string (it returns a newly allocated char*.

```
char* color_tags(char* s) {

    char* out = s;

    // in real, the table is much longer
    static char* table[4][2] = {
        {"<b>", BOLD},
        {"<u>", UNDERLINE},         
        {"</b>", BOLD_R},
        {"</u>", UNDERLINE_R},
    };


    for(int r=0; r<4; r++) {
        // here's what bothers me
        out = str_replace(table[r][0], table[r][1], out);
    }

    return out;
}
```

As you can see, the `char* out` is replaced by pointer to the new string, so the old string apparently ends up as a memory leak - if I don't understand it totally wrong.

What would be a better way for this?

Comment: Erm...you still have s floating around. As long as you don't modify it elsewhere, you can just `free(s);` later.

Comment: Does `str_replace` deallocate the old string?

Comment: No, it does not. For completeness sake, here's where I got str_replace: http://www.binarytides.com/str_replace-for-c/

Comment: Oh, no. It's a copy/paste lacking understanding.

Comment: Well I wrote this code myself, it's only str_replace I got from the other source. I'm not that good with strings yet. Anyway you can see what it does.

Comment: @ciphermagi, so what?  That's why OP is asking.

Comment: @Duck Actually, it's really not relevant to what he's asking. He's asking about his memory leak, and I already addressed that.

Comment: @ciphermagi Well, I don't understand you. I've been taught that a pointer is a place which holds an address. Since in my code, it's overwritten by address of the new string, I don't see how `free` could deallocate the old string. That's why I am asking, I'm not very familiar with this pointers stuff.

Comment: @MightyPork Oh, well, in that case, here it is: `char * out = s;` sets 'out' to the same value (address) as 's'. 's' never gets modified, so it's still pointing to the first address of the original string when your function goes out of scope, which means it's still a valid reference to the original string, while the new string is pointed to by 'out'. So you can still use it to free up the original string, since you didn't change 's', you only used it as a starting point for 'out'.

Comment: @ciphermagi If you actually bothered to see the source of str_replace, you'd see that it generates a whole new string, so after the first iteration, it's no longer the same string. Anyway I think @ abacabadabacaba has my answer, you can look if you agree with it.

Comment: @MightyPork The source of str_replace is irrelevant. You're not replacing it in place, you're creating a *totally new space for an additional string elsewhere*.

Comment: @ciphermagi of course, I know that. That's why asked in the first place. `free(s);` would not solve anything, except perhaps messing up the caller's string.

Comment: @MightyPork I said free it *later*. You can even wait until the very last line before you return from the main function, as long as it hasn't been modified or gone out of scope.

Comment: @ciphermagi Well, I think you don't understand me - this is not about the `s`. In the `for` loop, a new string is created each time, so in the end you have a bunch of allocated strings floating around.

Comment: @MightyPork Okay, use the obfuscated code below with the exact same leak from abacabadabacaba.

Comment: @ciphermagi exact same leak? mind showing me where / how it happens?

Comment: @MightyPork What's the difference between `x = 10; printf("%d\n", x);` and `x = 10; y = x; printf("%d\n", y);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code leaks 3 strings in total: one after each of the iterations except the last one. The solution is to deallocate each of those strings after its use. The code may look like this:

```
for(int r=0; r<4; r++) {
    char* new_out = str_replace(table[r][0], table[r][1], out);
    if (r>0) {
        // out is an intermediate value which will never be used again, free it
        free(out);
    }
    out = new_out;
}
```

Comment: actually after doing this, I got a weird memory violation error and it all fell to pieces. No idea what's up.

Comment: This might be because of an error somewhere else. In an unsafe language like C, errors may begin manifesting only after some unrelated change. You may try to use a program like Valgrind to find a source of the problem.

Comment: you're right, the problem is in str_replace, it causes incredible memory leaks.

Comment: -1, with this you will try to free the string literals that are initially assigned to the table entries.

Comment: @JensGustedt: That's not true.

Answer (score 1):

[This is more of a comment than an answer — [abacabadabacaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602809/abacabadabacaba) has already posted the answer — but I hope it will clarify things a bit.]

I would argue that the memory leak is in this statement:

> `str_replace` **internally** calls malloc to get space for the new string […]

[emphasis mine] Memory management is such a fundamental concern in C that if a function allocates memory that it itself doesn't de-allocate, then that is a major property of the function, and one that needs to be documented up-front, together with information about what the caller is supposed to do about it. It should not be considered "internal" to the function, and you shouldn't have the read the entirety of the function's source-code in order to determine it. It's enough to make me suspicious of the rest of the function (and indeed, a quick glance at that function is enough to notice a lot of issues: its parameter-types should be `const char *` rather than `char *`; it should check the return-value of `malloc`; it could be made more efficient by keeping track of the tail of `new_subject`, or cleaner by using `strcat`, instead of the current worst-of-both-worlds; etc.).

You didn't write `str_replace` originally, but you can modify your own version, so you should change its documentation from this:

> Search and replace a string with another string , in a string

to something like this:

> Creates and returns a copy of `subject`, but with all occurrences of the substring `search` replaced by `replace`. The returned string is newly allocated using `malloc`; the caller should use `free`.

(Your `color_tags` function will need similar documentation, since it too returns a newly-allocated string using `malloc`.)

That documentation in hand, there's a clear chain of "ownership": the caller of `str_replace` takes ownership of the string it returns. So `color_tags` has to call `free` for every string returned by `str_replace`, *except* the string that `color_tags` itself will return (which in turn will be "owned" by the caller of `color_tags`). Hence abacabadabacaba's answer.